# Crashlytics not showing some crashes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode8, crashlytics, google-fabric

I've added crashlytics in my app and I've uploaded a build in our private download site which is available for test users. The version which I had uploaded my build used crashlytics version 3.9.0. In my fabric dashboard I was getting crashlog and last crash log was dated last Thu, Nov 9. For past few days(since last friday) I've been getting report from users that they have experienced few crash which they are unable to reproduce and happens occasionally. But when I look at the fabric dashboard I don't see any new logs, the last log still dates Nov 9. Is there any reason why the latest crashes since last friday has not been updated on crashlytics. I've seen that crashlytics has released a new version 3.9.3. Could that be the issue? Will I need to update my crashlytics library in my app and re-upload the build for new crash reports? Any help is appreciated.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

//Initialize crashlytics
    [Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];
```

Comment: it often happens with me too, still i dint find root cause of this problem

Comment: We're also seeing this issue with Crashlytics 3.9.3 (Fabric 1.7.2). Latest Release shows a build with multiple crashes on it, however when tapping "Investigate this release's top issues in Crashlytics" it shows no crashes and says it's 100% crash free which I know for a fact is not true.

Comment: Thanks! Are you still running into this issue? Sometimes this can be caused by delays in processing. :)

Comment: I know about the delays but the maximum delay should be upto few hours and not days. I haven't got any logs on the crashes that were reported since Nov 10 and last crash report made by the app users was on Nov 13. And so far I've not received any logs, last log in crashlytics(Fabric) still dates to Nov 09.

Comment: Thanks. Are you getting any missing dSYM warnings? Also, please enable https://docs.fabric.io/apple/fabric/advanced-settings/debugging.html and supply the output in your original question. This will help :)

Comment: I'm not getting any warnings in fabric dashboard regarding any missing dSYM. I can enable the debug mode but wouldn't that require another build release to the test users?