# Crashlytics not showing some crashes in Android

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

Some of the crashes are visible in the dashboard, but some aren't. Does anyone know the reason behind and how to fix it?

Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

Initialising crashlytics

```
Fabric.with(this, Crashlytics())
```

[This one's open too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47278573/crashlytics-not-showing-some-crashes)

[**EDIT**]
One such crash that I managed to log begun with:

```
 io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed:
```

Comment: any specific types or crash which are not visible on dashboard ?

Comment: I am not sure, since I am unable to log them. I did have information on one such crash though, that I have updated in the question

Comment: update your crashlytics version to 2.9.7 and then give a try